# When are servlets instances created actually?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

According to the post [how do servlets work instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading) servlets, listeners and filters are instantiated when the server parses the `web.xml` file. But listeners and filters are only getting instantiated. Servlets are not getting instantiated.

So are servlets instantiated at parsing `web.xml` or when requests come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you **configured**.

If you want to instantiate during `startup`, you should give `<load-on-startup> in web.xml`

else Servlet is instantiated when the container receives the `first request`.

In either case the `same instance` is used to serve subsequent requests.

Comment: What about the accepted answer in the mentioned post

Comment: The second paragraph in the accepted answer telling exact the same thing :)

Comment: Didn't observe that.Thankyou